# How to get value in a column based on condition in pandas data frame pivot table?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, python-3.6

I have a MySQL table as shown below:

```
     ID   | article | price | promo_price | delivery_days | stock |  received_on
    17591   03D/6H   3082.00    1716.21         30            0      2019-03-20
    29315   03D/6H   3082.00    1716.21         26            0      2019-03-24
    47796   03D/6H   3082.00    1716.21         24            0      2019-03-25

    22016   L1620S    685.00    384.81           0            3      2019-03-20
    35043   L1620S    685.00    384.81           0            2      2019-03-24
    53731   L1620S    685.00    384.81           0            2      2019-03-25
```

I created a pivot table to monitor the stock data.

```
md = df.pivot_table(
        values='stock', 
        index=['article','price', 'promo_price','delivery_days'], 
        columns='received_on', 
        aggfunc=np.sum)

dates = md.columns.tolist()
dates.sort(reverse=True)

md = md[dates]
```

This is the resuslt

```
    +---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
    |                                 |   2019-03-25 |   2019-03-24 |   2019-03-20 |
    |---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------|
    | ('03D/6H', 3082.0, 1716.21, 24) |            0 |          nan |          nan |
    | ('03D/6H', 3082.0, 1716.21, 26) |          nan |            0 |          nan |
    | ('03D/6H', 3082.0, 1716.21, 30) |          nan |          nan |            0 |
    | ('L1620S-KD', 685.0, 384.81, 0) |            2 |            2 |            3 |
    +---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

How do I filter the rows and get the price, promo_price and delivery days of an article based on the recent stock received date?

For ex: I want the stock info for all the days but price, promo_price and delivery days of only 2019-03-25 as shown below

```
    +---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
    |                                 |   2019-03-25 |   2019-03-24 |   2019-03-20 |
    |---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------|
    | ('03D/6H', 3082.0, 1716.21, 24) |            0 |          nan |          nan |
    | ('L1620S', 685.0, 384.81, 0)    |            2 |            2 |            3 |
    +---------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**EDIT:**

If there is no change in price, promo_price and delivery days, I am getting the result as expected. But if there is any change in the values, then I am getting multiple rows for the same article.

Article **L1620S** data is as expected. But article **03D/6H** resulted in three rows.

Comment: Can you explain more `How do I filter the rows and get the price, promo_price and delivery days of an article based on the recent stock received date?

For ex: I want the stock info for all the days but price, promo_price and delivery days of only 2019-03-25 as shown below` ? Why is selected first row? Because if want select column with date, it is `md['2019-03-25']`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['received_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_on'])

md = df.pivot_table(
        values='stock', 
        index=['article','price', 'promo_price','delivery_days'], 
        columns='received_on', 
        aggfunc=np.sum)

#sorting columns in descending order
md = md.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)

#remove missing rows in first column
md = md.dropna(subset=[md.columns[0]])
#another solution 
#md = md[md.iloc[:, 0].notna()]
print (md)
received_on                               2019-03-25  2019-03-24  2019-03-20
article price  promo_price delivery_days                                    
03D/6H  3082.0 1716.21     24                    0.0         NaN         NaN
L1620S  685.0  384.81      0                     2.0         2.0         3.0
```

EDIT: First filter by first level and then by position - first row:

```
md = md.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)

idx = pd.IndexSlice
md1 = md.loc[idx['03D/6H',:,:],:].iloc[[0]]
print (md1)
received_on                               2019-03-25  2019-03-24  2019-03-20
article price  promo_price delivery_days                                    
03D/6H  3082.0 1716.21     24                    0.0         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: how did you get only the recent date values (price  promo_price delivery_days) ?

Comment: @Abhilash - Can you explain more?

Comment: for the article 03D/6H, how did you get only one row?

Comment: @Abhilash - Do you think after `md = md.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)` ?

Comment: Got it. Thank you jezreal. I Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: @jezreal, I am getting the date format as 2019-03-25 00:00:00, how do I change it to 2019-03-25?

Comment: @Abhilash - There are `00:00:00` in columns names? If yes, reason is at least one non `00:00:00` value, if need dates only use `df['received_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_on']).dt.floor('D')`

Comment: I tried this already. but still I am getting the date as 2019-03-25 00:00:00

Comment: @Abhilash - hmm, is is expected, because there are always datetimes, not dates. But if really need it use `df['received_on'] = pd.to_datetime(df['received_on']).dt.date`, but then possible some errors, because converting datetimes to python dates (objects)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Anyhow I am writing this data to Excel using ExcelWriter. So I managed to modify the date format using ExcelWriter(r'filepath', datetime_format='yyyy-dd-MM'). I appreciate your help.